# How many bits required for frame and offset number on 32-bit system with 1GB physical memory and 8KB page size?

Tags: operating-system, frame, offset, 32-bit

Doing some quick revision for a test, and its questions like these that always stump me:

How many bits required for the frame and offset number on 32-bit system with 1GB (2^30) physical memory and 8KB (2^13) page size?

For the Offset Number I got:

```
2^13 ~ 13 bits
```

For The Frame Number I got:

```
32-13 = 19 bits
```

Also it asks how many pages are available for the system but that was pretty simple:

```
2^30/2^13 = 2^17 pages
```

Just wanting to know if my answers are correct because I have doubts about the first two.

Thanks for the help! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no doubt about the first one. To address every byte in an 8K frame, you need 13 bits.

The second one is a bit more iffy. Although you may have 32 bits available to you in a "word", the question asks how many bits you *require* for a 1G address space (not the 4G you'd normally get from 32 bits). What you *require* is just those 17 bits, not the full 19.

And I agree with your third answer as well, 2<sup>17</sup> pages.

Comment: That was my first answers for the second question, except I thought it was a bit strange to have both the second question and the third question to have the same answers so I changed it to 2^19. I'm glad the other two are correct though, thanks for the help! :D